# Its possible to recive and send tokens by smartcontract?

Tags: contract-development

Is it possible to receive and send other tokens (like DAI for example) by smart contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you implement into your contract functions that allows it to interact with the contract that created the tokens, this is possible. If the token is a standard, like ERC20, the same code (changing only the address of the particular token) will work.

Comment: but for example, I want to create smart contract that will hold DAI send by group of people, then invoking contract method send all DAI to one of them, it is possible?

Comment: Yes. This is possible and is not difficult to do, but you need to know what functions are implemented in the contract. If it is ERC20 then using `transfer` function is all you will need in your contract.

Comment: thanks for help, I am trying find source code DAI contract, but I can not find them, on etherscan there is no source code tab, maybe some clues?

Comment: I tried as well but couldn't find it.

Comment: Here is the sourcecode for DAI token :) https://etherscan.io/address/0x89d24a6b4ccb1b6faa2625fe562bdd9a23260359#code